# ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server

Tags: php, ldap

I can remote access in using the admin username and password which I'm using the same username and password in the script.  but I get the following error

Warning: ldap_bind(): Unable to bind to server: Can't contact LDAP server in

Could not bind to the server. Check the username/password.
Server Response:
Error Number: -1
Description: Can't contact LDAP server

```
<?php
    ini_set('display_errors',1);
    ini_set('display_startup_errors',1);
    error_reporting(-1);

     // Username used to connect to the server
     $username = "Administrator";

     // Password of the user.
     $password = "password";

     // Either an IP or a domain.
     $ldap_server = "10.10.10.10";

     // Get a connection
     $ldap_conn = ldap_connect($ldap_server);

     // Set LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION to 3
     ldap_set_option($ldap_conn, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3) or die ("Could not set LDAP Protocol version");

     // Authenticate the user and link the resource_id with
     // the authentication.
     if($ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldap_conn, $username, $password) == true)
     {
     // Setup the data that will be used to create the user
     // This is in the form of a multi-dimensional
     // array that will be passed to AD to insert.
     $adduserAD["cn"] = "testuser";
     $adduserAD["sn"] = "User";
     $adduserAD["samaccountname"] = "testuser";
     $adduserAD["objectClass"] = "user";
     $adduserAD["displayname"] = "Test User";
     $adduserAD["userPassword"] = "Welcome123!";
     $adduserAD["userAccountControl"] = 544;

     $base_dn = "cn=testuser,cn=Users,DC=testdomain,DC=com";

     // Display some "waiting" text.
     echo "Trying to add the user to the system ...<br>";

     // Attempt to add the user with ldap_add()
     if(ldap_add($ldap_conn, $base_dn, $adduserAD) == true)
     {

     // The user is added and should be ready to be logged
     // in to the domain.
     echo "User added!<br>";
     }else{

     // This error message will be displayed if the user
     // was not able to be added to the AD structure.
     echo "Sorry, the user was not added.<br>Error Number: ";
     echo ldap_errno($ldap_conn) . "<br />Error Description: ";
     echo ldap_error($ldap_conn) . "<br />";
     }
     }else{
     echo "Could not bind to the server. Check the username/password.<br />";
     echo "Server Response:"

     // Error number.
     . "<br />Error Number: " . ldap_errno($ldap_conn)

     // Error description.
     . "<br />Description: " . ldap_error($ldap_conn);
     }

     // Always make sure you close the server after
     // your script is finished.
     ldap_close($ldap_conn);
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you ping the server?  Have you tried an LDAP browser to verify connecting outside of PHP?  What have you done so far?

Comment: I can ping the server, and connect and run other php scripts just fine.  I've made sure that ldap is enabled in my php manager on IIS 7.5.

Comment: Can you run a basic ldapsearch on the command line and what is the output ? You can ping the server but can you telnet on the target port ? WHich port ? By the way you are using `ldap_connect($ldap_server);` without specifying $port so the connection defaults with ldap:// protocol on port 389. Your server may require ldap**s**:// protocol (usually on port 636), or even StartTLS over ldap:// on port 389 (-Z option on cmd line), anyway if you need SSL/TLS, check that you have a copy of the CA certificate on your client machines.

Answer (score -2):

You should check the result of your first `ldap_connect(...)` call.

And:

Try [something like this](http://www.ldapadmin.org/) [or this](http://jxplorer.org/) to validate all of your connection information.  This has been very helpful to me to make sure you have the right account information and LDAP directory information.

Answer (score -2):

why following line doesn't have port in it?

```
$ldap_server = "10.10.10.10";
$ldap_conn = ldap_connect($ldap_server);
```

try something like below

```
 if($authMethod == 0){
    $ldap_server = 'ldap://'.$host.':'.$port;
}else if($authMethod == 1) {
    $ldap_server = 'ldaps://'.$host.':'.$port;
}
$ldap_conn = ldap_connect($ldap_server);
```

and then check $ldap_conn is true or false or any other return code.
port#389 is default for simple LDAP and 636 for LDAPS.
I hope this should work :). Cheers!!!!